# Ionic 4 [Google Maps]

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I need a hand with Google Maps in Ionic 4. I add the plugin and install the beta version (which is the one that allows ngx). Until then I arrived well. In the page that I'm going to implement, I follow the basic steps to show the map and I see all the blank in the area where I have the div with the ID where the map is loaded.

I can not find a solution, at least for the moment. Failing that because of what I saw, I can integrate openMaps that would also be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a width and height for your map?

```
#map {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Please post your controller, html, and scss